# How to force Ubuntu One contacts sync with Evolution?

Tags: ubuntu-one, evolution

I am using Evolution in Ubuntu 11.04, and I have encountered a problem with trying to synchronize contacts with Ubuntu One when they are created through the web interface. The contacts I have created this way will not sync into my Evolution contacts.

I have searched for people having the same issue but couldn't find anything. So my question is: how can I force Ubuntu One to update all my contacts in Evolution to match those in the web interface?

Comment: I have had very poor luck with Ubuntu One's contact syncing. If you can stomach it, I'd highly recommend using Google Contacts instead. It appears to work better with Evolution, and will work under Thunderbird as well.

Comment: Or Funambol. I've been unable to get contact sync working with UbuntuOne, too. I'm syncing to Funambol via Thunderbird which works fine.

Comment: I should probably also add that I've been able to successfully sync my contacts just the first time after reinstalling Ubuntu when 11.04 came out, and also any contacts that I've made in Evolution after that. Just the ones I made specifically through the U1 web interface don't sync. Should I report this as a bug?

Comment: @CraigM, I've actually started using Thunderbird more than Evolution lately, and I've just kept the latter for the easy contacts sync. I might try looking into that.

Comment: @WarriorIng64: I'd report that as a bug, or at least find the bug report and add yourself as being affected by the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu One contacts and bookmarks sync (desktop-couch sync) is not functional. You can see the status here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status. When it's up again, all contacts you have in desktop-couch contact lists will automatically be synced.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yay, it's like 10.04 LTS all over again.