# How to sync contacts from Ubuntu One to Evolution

Tags: ubuntu-one, evolution, contacts

I have all my contacts saved in Ubuntu One via the web.  I would like to sync all those contacts with Evolution.  I can find all kinds of info on syncing from Evolution to Ubuntu One, but I want to do it the other way around.  I am using Ubuntu 11.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable Contact sync with Ubuntu One as per [these steps](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Contacts), it should work. There should be no difference in procedure for getting contacts from U1 to Evolution. If it still doesn't work for you, then you may be facing [my issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53108/how-to-force-ubuntu-one-contacts-sync-with-evolution).